# ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/sampai/Desktop/Repos/task_tracker/task_tracker/build/index.html'

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

So I am trying to create my backend routes for my full stack MERN application (with mysql). My application uses sequelize as my ORM and when I tried writing the get route for getting the data out of the database, this error comes up

"ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/sampai/Desktop/Repos/task_tracker/task_tracker/build/index.html' "

Below is my get request in my controller file.

```
module.exports = function(router) {
    router.get("/api/tasks", (req, res) => {
        db.Task.findAll({}).then(data => {
            res.json(data);
        });
    });
}
```

Below is my server.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const db = require("./models");

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.get("ping", function (req, res) {
    return res.send("pong");
})

app.get("*", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
})

require("./controllers/taskController")(app);

db.sequelize.sync().then(function() {

    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log("Your API server is now on PORT:", PORT);
    })

})
```

And lastly, below is my sequelize model

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){
    var Task = sequelize.define("Task", {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        task: DataTypes.STRING
    });
return Task;
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out why I am getting this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ACtually I figured it out, I just got rid of that app.get with the build, index.html statement in the server.js and it worked!